# Handle onkeypress events for focused rowss

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to invoke a java script function on key press on a table row which has focus. Below is the code, but when I press Enter key script function is not invoked.

http://jsfiddle.net/sirishkumar/58FZG/19/

```
<input id="test" type="text">
<table>
    <tr onkeypress="return openLog(e,'row 1')">
        <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr onkeypress="return openLog(e,'row 2')">
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
</table>


var j = jQuery;
var currentRow = 0;
var pagesize = 2;

function ChangeCurrentRow() {
    var tableRow = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[(currentRow % pagesize)];
    tableRow.focus();
    j(tableRow).siblings().removeClass("highlight-row");
    j(tableRow).addClass("highlight-row");
}

j(document).ready(function () {
    j('#test').val("Ready");
    ChangeCurrentRow();

});

j(document).keydown(function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        currentRow--;
        ChangeCurrentRow();
        return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        currentRow++;
        ChangeCurrentRow();
        return false;
    }
});


function openLog(e, id) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#input').text(id)
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct keyCode? I checked, the `keydown` event IS actually firing.

Comment: Yes http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes .

Comment: @sweetamylase How can I see key events in firebug ? Are you using different tool

Comment: In your firebug, click on the Console tab and enable it. In your 'keydown` function, just add `console.log(e)` and it'll output your event object to the Console window when the event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "focusing" for rows. Your `focus()` do nothing. Just try to write:

```
j(tableRow).focus(function(){alert('test');});
tableRow.focus();
```

And you will see nothing =)
Try to handle keypress event in a `$(document).keypress()` and do manipulations with selected row. `onkeypress` for tr - do nothing (except `contenteditable="true"` tr).

Comment: I didn't understand your comment completely. So you are saying there is no meaning to focusing rows and Enter key event is not sent to the focused element, in this case focused row. Why is that?

Comment: @Sirish I don't know why, sorry. I just write the code above to test focusing on "tr" tag, and "onfocus" event was not fired.